# Write CMakeLists.txt for boost::mpi

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, mpi

The cmake file below is the source of problem because I can compile the code with mpic++ directly and without using cmake.

Why the cmake file below doesn't work?

Current cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(boost_mpi_cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

add_executable(test test.cpp)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED mpi system)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
include_directories(${MPI_CXX_INCLUDE_PATH})
target_link_libraries(test ${MPI_CXX_LIBRARIES})
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;
int main()
{
  mpi::environment env;
  mpi::communicator world;
  std::string s(env.processor_name());
  std::cout << s << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::mpi::environment::processor_name[abi:cxx11]()", referenced from:
      _main in test.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Compile without cmake works:

```
mpic++ test.cpp -lboost_mpi
```

Comment: Does `mpic++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -loost_mpi` work? Also in general, please share more information, e.g. the output of `make VERBOSE=1`, `cmake -LAH . | grep "MPI\|Boost"`

Comment: If `c++11` doesn't build, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668560/boost-unit-test-link-error-abi-mismatch. The ABI-Hell is a really nasty and complicated thing, I can't find a better SO discussion about it right now.

Comment: c++11 still builds. I found that if I don't use the env.processor_name() then it compiles. I am testing if send and recv work now.